# How to make KDE Homerun opaque?

Tags: kde, transparency

I have recently had some issues with the ordinary KDE Application Launcher (it froze my plasma for a while...), so I decided to give Homerun a try. Homerun seems really good at first glance, but how can I make the background opaque or at least less transparent? Currently the transparency seems to be ~50% which makes it difficult to read anything from it.

I am running Raring Kubuntu with KDE 4.11.1

Answer (score 0):

**Blur**

The Homerun seems /1/ to use the plasma blur setting: KDE System setting > Desktop effects > Appearance - Blur.

[image]

Something to check: Is the blur working ?
How much do you have the blur ?

1. Based to the feedback of the Kubuntu developers: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/2013-September/007343.html

Other KDE Launchers: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59851-KDE-Application-Launchers

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I have the Blur effect turned off. And I have tried disabling the Transparency effect, didn't help either. Only disabling all the effects did the trick, but that's not necessarily what I want :/